# Ubuntu 22 suddenly stopped booting

Tags: boot, 22.04

I have been using Ubuntu for my personal computer for the last year, including the 22 version since its release. However, the last week my computer started to have problems booting the system. It just freezes, showing a flickering "_".

```
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop audit[1159]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/snapd/17336/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1159 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1666639466.040:49): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/snapd/17336/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=1159 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[1185]: [session uid=127 pid=1185] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files' unit='tracker-miner-fs-3.service' requested by ':1.2' (uid=127 pid=1160 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-extract-3 " label="unconfined")
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (==) Matched nouveau as autoconfigured driver 0
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 1.0.17
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         Module class: X.Org Video Driver
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 1.21.1
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         Module class: X.Org Video Driver
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.5.0
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         Module class: X.Org Video Driver
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 2.5.0
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         Module class: X.Org Video Driver
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) NOUVEAU driver Date:   Sat Jan 23 12:24:42 2021 -0500
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         RIVA TNT            (NV04)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         RIVA TNT2           (NV05)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         GeForce 256         (NV10)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         GeForce 2           (NV11, NV15)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         GeForce 4MX         (NV17, NV18)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         GeForce 3           (NV20)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         GeForce 4Ti         (NV25, NV28)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         GeForce FX          (NV3x)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         GeForce 6           (NV4x)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         GeForce 7           (G7x)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         GeForce 8           (G8x)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         GeForce 9           (G9x)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         GeForce GTX 2xx/3xx (GT2xx)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         GeForce GTX 4xx/5xx (GFxxx)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         GeForce GTX 6xx/7xx (GKxxx)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         GeForce GTX 9xx     (GMxxx)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         GeForce GTX 10xx    (GPxxx)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Starting Tracker file system data miner...
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop tracker-miner-f[1226]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &DOCUMENTS. Ignoring this location.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop tracker-miner-f[1226]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &MUSIC. Ignoring this location.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop tracker-miner-f[1226]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &PICTURES. Ignoring this location.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop tracker-miner-f[1226]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &VIDEOS. Ignoring this location.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop tracker-miner-f[1226]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &DOWNLOAD. Ignoring this location.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop tracker-miner-f[1226]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &DOCUMENTS. Ignoring this location.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop tracker-miner-f[1226]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &MUSIC. Ignoring this location.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop tracker-miner-f[1226]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &PICTURES. Ignoring this location.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop tracker-miner-f[1226]: Unable to get XDG user directory path for special directory &VIDEOS. Ignoring this location.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[1185]: [session uid=127 pid=1185] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=127 pid=1226 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3 " label="unconfined")
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor...
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (EE) [drm] Failed to open DRM device for pci:0000:81:00.0: -19
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.0.2
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (EE) Unable to find a valid framebuffer device
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.0.2
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:         ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) FBDEV(2): using default device
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (EE)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: Fatal server error:
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (EE)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (EE)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:          at http://wiki.x.org
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]:  for help.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (EE)
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[1185]: [session uid=127 pid=1185] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor'
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Started Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[1185]: [session uid=127 pid=1185] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=127 pid=1226 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3 " label="unconfined")
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor...
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[1185]: [session uid=127 pid=1185] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor'
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Started Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[1185]: [session uid=127 pid=1185] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-afc-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=127 pid=1226 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3 " label="unconfined")
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor...
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[1185]: [session uid=127 pid=1185] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor'
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Started Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[1185]: [session uid=127 pid=1185] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=127 pid=1226 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3 " label="unconfined")
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor...
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[1185]: [session uid=127 pid=1185] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor'
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Started Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[1185]: [session uid=127 pid=1185] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-goa-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=127 pid=1226 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3 " label="unconfined")
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor...
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[1185]: [session uid=127 pid=1185] Activating service name='org.gnome.OnlineAccounts' requested by ':1.15' (uid=127 pid=1257 comm="/usr/libexec/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor " label="unconfined")
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1168]: (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1166]: Unable to run X server
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop gdm-launch-environment][1144]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop goa-daemon[1261]: goa-daemon version 3.44.0 starting
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop gdm-launch-environment][1144]: GLib-GObject: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop gdm3[1139]: Gdm: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Deactivated successfully.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd-logind[901]: Session c1 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[1185]: [session uid=127 pid=1185] Activating service name='org.gnome.Identity' requested by ':1.16' (uid=127 pid=1261 comm="/usr/libexec/goa-daemon " label="unconfined")
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd-logind[901]: Removed session c1.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[1185]: [session uid=127 pid=1185] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.OnlineAccounts'
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[1185]: [session uid=127 pid=1185] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor'
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 620 (plymouthd).
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Started Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[876]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.UPower' unit='upower.service' requested by ':1.40' (uid=127 pid=1226 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs-3 " label="unconfined")
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[1185]: [session uid=127 pid=1185] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Identity'
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Daemon for power management...
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop gdm3[1297]: modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[876]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.41' (uid=127 pid=1158 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined")
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop rtkit-daemon[1169]: Supervising 4 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop rtkit-daemon[1169]: Supervising 4 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop rtkit-daemon[1169]: Supervising 4 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop rtkit-daemon[1169]: Supervising 4 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop rtkit-daemon[1169]: Supervising 4 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Started Sound Service.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1]: tmp-snap.rootfs_pqvu1t.mount: Deactivated successfully.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration[1159]: Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently supported.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration[1159]: See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[876]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.UPower'
oct 24 21:24:26 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1]: Started Daemon for power management.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Started Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration[1312]: Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently supported.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration[1312]: See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop dbus-daemon[1185]: [session uid=127 pid=1185] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files'
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Started Tracker file system data miner.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Reached target Main User Target.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Startup finished in 1.290s.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Started Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration[1343]: Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently supported.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration[1343]: See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Started Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration[1375]: Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently supported.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration[1375]: See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Started Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration[1405]: Sorry, home directories outside of /home are not currently supported.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration[1405]: See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details.
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
oct 24 21:24:27 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
oct 24 21:24:28 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
oct 24 21:24:28 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Stopped Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
oct 24 21:24:28 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
oct 24 21:24:28 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
oct 24 21:24:28 ubuntu-desktop systemd[1149]: Failed to start Service for snap application snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration.
```

I have reinstalled Ubuntu twice, but the bug reappears after a couple days of normal functioning. I have analyzed the journals, but my knowledge is limited and I don't really understand what is happening.

This part is retried several times, so maybe the source of the bug is here. I'm sorry for the dense question, but I'm a bit lost about what to do.

Comment: `modprobe: FATAL: Module nvidia not found in directory /lib/modules/5.15.0-52-generic` is the problem. How exactly have you installed Nvidia drivers?

Comment: About the nvidia drivers, I didn't install the official drivers directly, I used the default ones. About the re installation, I even replace the SSD the second time, it was a completely clear installation. Maybe is something that I installed, but apart from the drivers of a wifi antenna, there wasn't anything really complex or troubling.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question... What did you install after system installation that is not in the default official repositories? What modifications have you made that are not options available in the stock interface?  This is important to know the exact details because your problem keeps reoccurring after you do these things.